# Does quarkus reactive sql client support tracing?

Tags: java, quarkus, datadog, distributed-tracing, quarkus-reactive

I was trying to enable jdbc tracing in my quarkus service.

I had `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.tracing=true` in the property file, and `implementation "io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-jdbc:0.2.15"` in the gradle build file.

The migration was done through flyway (`implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-flyway'`) and all sql queries to handle the business logic is done through the reactive postgres client (`implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-pg-client'`).

I use datadog to gather the traces.

```
          - -Ddd.trace.propagation.style.inject=datadog,b3multi
          - -Ddd.trace.propagation.style.extract=datadog,b3multi
          - -Ddd.agent.host=$(DD_AGENT_HOST)
          - -Ddd.integrations.enabled=true
          - -Ddd.trace.enabled=true
          - -Ddd.logs.injection=true
          - -Ddd.jmxfetch.enabled=false
          - -Ddd.dbm.propagation.mode=full
          - -Ddd.integration.jdbc-datasource.enabled=true
          - -javaagent:/deployments/dd-java-agent.jar
          - -Ddd.profiling.enabled=false
```

After the service is deployed, I can observe traces from datadog. There are traces for DB migration, such as
[image]
I can also see the traces for http request:
[image]
However, for such request that queries the postgres, I am expecting spans of postgres query, but there are none.

Does quarkus reactive sql client support tracing? There are no documents from (https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients). From the data source document (https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource), tracing seems to be only supported in the non-reactive data source?

Comment: To better understand the problem, can you please share how the Reactive Pg Client is used? Directly or through Hibernate Reactive? Thank you

Comment: @tsegismont
the pg client was used directly, not through any ORM framework.

Answer (score 2):

With reactive stack you don't need `io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-jdbc` the reactive stack doesn't use JDBC but the `quarkus-reactive-pg-client`. You probably get that error because there are no recognisable tracing frameworks on the classpath.

There are many tracing frameworks and you need to choose one, just saying you want tracing without specifying an instrumentation framework, won't create or send your traces anywhere.

On Quarkus we recommend OpenTelemetry Tracing. For reactive applications these are the recommended dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```